# Sending click/tap coordinates to a server

Tags: jquery, ajax, tap

I have a Div around 960x640.
I have to send click/tap  coordinates to a server.
Obviously I need it without reloading the page. I think the code need optimization.

```
<div id="area2" style="width:960px; height:640; background-color:#ffaaaa"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// click event 
    $('#area2').click(function(e) { 
        // Take the coordinates
        var posX = e.offsetX; 
        var posY = e.offsetY; 
        // Ajax calls
        $.ajax({ 
            url:'file.php', 
            data:{posX:posX, posY:posY}, 
            type:'POST', 
            success: function(result) { 
                // Data sent
                alert("Data sent"); 
            }, 
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("ohi! "+textStatus+" - " +errorThrown); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

PHP

```
$db_conn=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die ("Error connection!");
    $beta=mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Error database selection!");

$posX=intval($_POST["posX"]);
$posY=intval($_POST["posX"]);
    $UpdatePlayer = mysql_query("UPDATE players SET x=$posX, y=$posY  WHERE fb_user=$user") or die ("Error update players");
```

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions: "*How do I get the x/y coordinates of a click/touch event in JavaScript?*", "*How do I send data using Ajax?*", and "*How do I store in MySQL some values delivered via Ajax to a PHP script?*" If you *don't* know how to do any of these things, I'd suggest learning the relevant technologies first (and then asking separate questions if you still don't understand something). If you *do* know how to do some of these, tell us, so you can narrow down your question and answers can provide the exact advice you actually need.

Comment: The first one:
 "How do I get the x/y coordinates of a click/touch event?"
I am skilled on PHP and MySQL. Basically I need how can I obtain coordinates and prepare to sent them. I know there are library like jQuery.spritely but I need not necessarily those

Comment: If you're skilled in php and mysql, why are you not escaping your values?  Your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.  Also, use [PDO](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: You are right Daedalus. I put intval() in php code to prevent injection. How can I prevent click / tap too frequent?
Thanks